# Altering Eclipse build order

Tags: eclipse, maven, build-process

I'm using maven to build out my java projects which is shared between my team but because of eclipse build order my projects are built in an alphabetical order. Is there a file or specific place where I can alter this build order and push it out to my team?

Comment: You can define the order of the project in parent `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Thats the thing i did. But for some reason the build order gets overridden by eclipse default build order. So for sure I can run a maven install which will build everything out. The problem with that, is that I have to manually click on the file to run: maven clean and maven install. I was under the assumption that eclipse would use my master pom file to run everything instead of using it's default build order

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse determines the build order from project dependencies. If you use [m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), Eclipse should understand the dependencies from pom.xml and list dependent projects under the "Maven Dependencies" node in the Package Explorer.

OTOH, if there were no dependencies between projects, why bother about build order?

Comment: There are clear dependencies but it's over 40 projects being imported in as maven projects and whenever eclipses does a build instead of choosing to follow the maven build order it goes by its default build path

Comment: Both Eclipse and Maven compute a valid build order from the set of known dependencies. What difference does it make which of these valid orders is used? I don't even think the actual order used by Maven is strictly documented.